# How do I get an array of properties from an array of objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

In my Rails 3 application, I've got `current_account.users`.

What I want is a list of the names of all the users i.e. `user.full_name`. What's the most elegant way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If full_name is a column on the model, you can use the `pluck` method. That would look like `current_account.users.pluck(:full_name)`. If not, you can use `map` or `collect` (same thing), which would look like `current_account.users.map(&:full_name)` or `current_account.users.collect(&:full_name)`.

Comment: technically pluck and (map or collect) are not the same thing, as pluck selects only the column in question:

current_account.users.select(:full_name).map(&:full_name) would more precisely be the same thing as pluck.

If the user table has large text or binary blobs for profile information and there are many rows, this becomes a notable distinction from a performance standpoint.

Comment: I meant that `collect` and `map` are the same thing. The reason I mentioned `pluck` first was exactly because of that performance enhancement.